# Get value of <select> the modern way?

Tags: javascript

I was [under the impression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/how-to-get-the-selected-value-of-dropdownlist-using-javascript) that in order to get the value from `<select>` you essentially had to do this:

```
var sel = document.getElementById("my-select");
var val = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
```

But I [ran into some code today](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/3WYGc/) that simply does `document.getElementById('my-select').value`, which seems to work perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox.

Has this changed recently, or has it always been this way? How far back is this supported?

Comment: Old versions of IE wouldn't do that, but I'm pretty sure even IE7 supports it.

Comment: It's always been like that, the select gets the same value as the selected option.

Comment: It's not what you expect when you use `multiple="multiple"`, and you have to use the first method in order to get the selected option's `.text`. Otherwise it's fine to just get the `.value` of the select

Comment: you can also SET .value with any of the options and it magically works.

Comment: One gotcha- IE8- will not return the text if there is no value for the selected option, but the others do. IE does send the text along with a form submission, when there is no value. Go figure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mySelect.value` is a W3C standard at least since October 1st, 1998. See the [DOM Level 1 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-html.html#ID-59351919). However, some IE browsers released after that date do not support it, including IE8 (I just tested it).

**Edit:** As @kennebec pointed out, the issue with IE8 is that it wont use the option's text when there is no value set. If all your options do have a value set, then `myselect.value` will work on IE8.

Comment: that Microsoft as standart-wise as allways